# Get post ID of either existing post or new post

Tags: custom-post-types

If i'm using the following:

```
post_exists( $class_post_title ) or wp_insert_post( $class_post );
```

How can I get the ID of either the post that exists, or the post that has been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/) for `post_exists()`:

> **Return**
>   *(int)* Post ID if post exists, 0 otherwise.

So you can get the ID just by assigning the result of `post_exists()` to a variable:

```
$post_id = post_exists( $class_post_title );
```

The same thing works for `wp_insert_post()`:

> **Return**
>   *(int|WP_Error)* The post ID on success. The value 0 or WP_Error on failure.

So you can do this:

```
$post_id = post_exists( $class_post_title );

if ( ! $post_id ) {
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $class_post );
}

// $post_id is now the ID of whichever post exists or was created.
```